# WordPress Gravity Forms Send Notifications Dynamically to WP Users by User Role

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a WordPress site with Gravity Forms handling forms. I have a form that I want to send to all users with a specific User Role. Everything I've found in the GF docs shows how to use their tools in the dashboard - but I can't find anything about sending to email addresses dynamically.

Is there any way to handle setting up notification recipients dynamically without going through the dashboard? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom plugin add-on for that. As far as I know there isn't one out there. I've tried to accomplish the same result, but haven't deemed it viable to develop my own add-on for it yet. Might do it when I get the time.

Also, consider moving the question to the wordpress development SE.